# Expected value of a maximum function

Tags: probability

I found many resources about taking the expected value of a max function with random variables but stuck on one example in which we have a constant:

$$ E[\max(2x - 1, 0)] $$

where x follows a uniform distribution on [0, 1].

Comment: well, $2x-1$ is anyway a random variable

Answer (score 3):

$$
\int_{0}^{1}\max(2x-1,0) \, \mathrm{d}x
=\int_{1/2}^{1}2x-1 \, \mathrm{d}x
$$

Comment: Thanks so much, did you basically ignore the integral of 0 on [0, 1/2]?

Comment: $\max\{ 2x - 1, 0 \} = 0$ on $[0, 1/2]$

Comment: Wasn't "ignored".  Integrates to zero.

Comment: thanks so much again!

Comment: I have a follow-up question on the topic: how to calculate $$ E(\max((1.5xy+0.5)/2, 1/2)) $$ where x follows a uniform distribution on [0, 1] and y follows a binomial distribution?

Comment: @lemon: You're generally supposed to post a new question, not followup in the comments. Regardless, the technique for your followup is the same. Split the integral into multiple integrals over a disjoint union of the original domain that makes the integration easy (e.g., $\int_a^c f = \int_a^b f + \int_b^c f$ where $a < b < c$)

Comment: @parsiad sorry for my ignorance, I am new to the forum. My point is how I should treat the multiplication of a uniform and a binomial variable.

Comment: @lemon: Post a new question

Comment: @parsiad alright, thanks